# How can I map 3 lists to dictionary keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Im trying to create a type of todo list application. The problem is this:

All the task names are stored in a list. 
All the due dates are stored in a different list.
And so on. How can I combine these lists to get a dictionary like this.

```
task_names = ['test1', 'hw 1']
date_due = ['17 Dec', '16 Jan']

given_task = [{
    'name' : 'test1',
    'date_due' : '17 Dec', 
  }
, {
    'name' : 'hw1',
    'date_due' : '16 Jan', 
  }]
```

Comment: You need to show some attempt to solve it and ask a specific question about why your code doesnt work

Comment: also you given_task isnt a valid python data structure? is it to be a list of dicts?

Comment: @llko1810 check out this link:  https://ideone.com/DRTV06 There are many other way.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you want something like this

```
given_task = [{'name': i, 'date_due': j} for i, j in zip(task_names, date_due)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using `zip` and `dict` in a list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
task_names = ['test1', 'hw 1']
date_due = ['17 Dec', '16 Jan']
keys = ['name', 'date_due']

print([dict(zip(keys, i)) for i in zip(task_names, date_due)])
```

**Output:**

```
[{'date_due': '17 Dec', 'name': 'test1'},
 {'date_due': '16 Jan', 'name': 'hw 1'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: `given_task` is no valid python structure. I think you want a list filled with dictionaries like

```
    given_task = [{
        'name' : 'test1',
        'date_due' : '17 Dec', 
      }
    , {
        'name' : 'hw1',
        'date_due' : '16 Jan', 
      }]
```

As far as I understand, there are always the same amount of task names and taskdates. In this case you can iterate over all tasks and add them to a list.

```
    given_task = []
    for i in range(len(task_names)):
        given_task.append({'name':task_names[i],'date_due':dates_due[i]})
```